# Comma before "as well as" in a series

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

I am writing a text in which I use the serial comma ("Oxford comma").

*Example*: `She used to play with Ben, Alice, and Tom.`

Do I still need a comma if I replace the `and` with `as well as`?

*Example*: `She used to play with Ben, Alice, as well as Tom.`

Comment: You still need an *and*. For example *She used to play with Ben and Alice, as well as Tom.*

Comment: @Peter Yes, you need to treat both parts as lists in their own right. If you have three names in both lists you would have "...Charlie, Ben and Alice, as well as Tom, Sandra and Rachel."